# .replacement.highlight = true in MS Word VBA does not work

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, highlighting

I'm working on a larger project in Excel VBA and encountered the following problem. I'm using VBA to make Excel compile a template in MS Word. I wanted to highlight certain phrases in the template yellow. It used to work at some point, but then it stopped, for no apparent reason. When I run the code now, the part gets executed without errors, but the words don't get highlighted, even though I am sure they are there in the template. I used debug.print to find out the values of the .replacement.highlight value, and it shows me 9999999 in the Immediate window, and -1 if I hover the mouse cursor over the expression in break mode.

The relevant fragment of the code is quoted below:

```
Dim WdApp As Word.Application
Set WdApp = New Word.Application
With WdApp
    .ActiveDocument.Select
    With .Selection.Find
    'the code creating the document and writing the template continues here
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "{Optional: Please also confirm the terms of transactions and other key information (for example: rights of return, allowances and rebates, special agreements, payment terms, incoterms, etc.) which may affect the accounting for the transactions.}"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = PlaceholderAdditionalInfoRequest
        .Replacement.Text = .Text
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<<<@@@Client's Letterhead@@@>>>"
        .Replacement.Text = .Text
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "{Optional: A statement of account with the above invoices marked is attached. ALTERNATIVELY: Copies of the above invoices are attached.}"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
   End With
End With
```

Does any one know what's going on? I'd appreciate any pointers, especially if expressed in plain English :) I'm new to VBA and don't have a formal education in programming.

Best regards,

Tyro

Comment: I haven't tried your code but have you tried using ".Replacement.ClearFormatting" as well as .ClearFormatting before you set up .Replacement.Highlight? (Just in case something is "sticking" when it shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
```

before:

```
With .Selection.Find
```

It seems that you are applying the `Find` function not to the template but to a document activated before the creation of the template.
Try moving these lines:

`the code creating the document and writing the template continues here…`

before these line:

`.ActiveDocument.Select
    With .Selection.Find`

Make the Word Application `WdApp` visible (`WdApp.Visible = True`) to see what the code is doing and ensure it's closed ( `WdApp.Quit`) after the task is completed.

Comment: At first it seemed like it would work, but then it stopped. It seems like restarting the system (not just the application) helps, but the issue is rather erratic, I'm finding it hard to pin it down to any particular scenario. Has anyone been experiencing similar issues?

Comment: Hi, not yet. I'v left my laptop in the office so can't give it a try over the weekend, but I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you. Still, I don't think I'm applying the .find function to the wrong document, because if I type .Replacement.Text= "abc" it will get replaced in the appropriate document. I would also prefer not to quit the document at the end of the sub routine to allow the user to edit the template. I do set WdApp to nothing when the sub ends though, I think. I'll try the .Replacement.ClearFormatting and see how that works.

Comment: I guess one of the solutions worked. I haven't had the problem ever since. However, I've not had time to test it extensively, as I was busy with other stuff,too. Anyways, thank for help.